# JAVA - Criar uma instancia de um objeto de uma classe?

Tags: java, reflexão

Então,

Eu tenho uma classe chamada "GeraForm" que eu preciso que a mesma retorne uma string no estilo HTML form com algumas informações contidas em uma anotação. Eu consegui que o código funcione quando eu passo uma determinada classe para ele, mas eu gostaria que o código, antes de retornar a String, criasse uma instância de um objeto da classe para que, aí sim, eu pudesse ler as anotações dos métodos desse objeto e gerar o HTML form.

O que acontece é que, quando vou pegar o valor dos campos na anotação, como por exemplo

```
String label = annotation.label();
```

Eu estou obtendo um nullPointerException, que creio que seja pela falta de um objeto.

A minha anotação ***Campo.java***:

```
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;
import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;

@Target( { ElementType.METHOD } )
@Retention( RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME )
public @interface Campo {

    int maxLength() default 0;

    boolean required() default false;

    String label();

}
```

Minha classe ***GeraForm.Java***:

```
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

public class GeraForm {

    public String incluir(Class<?> formClass) throws NoSuchMethodException, SecurityException, IllegalAccessException, IllegalArgumentException, InvocationTargetException {
        Class<?> wantedClass = formClass;
        Method[] classMethods = wantedClass.getDeclaredMethods();
        String methodName = "temp";

        //I need to return a String in HTML form style at the and of the method
        //Im gonna construct the string piece by piece to return at the end of the method
        String returnString = "a";

        //I get the name of the method and put it to lower case
        for(int i=0; i < classMethods.length; i++) {
            if(classMethods[i].getName().startsWith("set")) {
                methodName = classMethods[i].getName().substring(3, classMethods[i].getName().length()).toLowerCase();
            }
        }

        Campo annotation = classMethods[0].getAnnotation(Campo.class);

        //Here I get the value of every field in the annotation
        String label = annotation.label(); 
        int maxLength = annotation.maxLength();
        boolean required = annotation.required();

        returnString = label+"<input type=\"text\" name=\""+methodName+"\"";
       if(maxLength != 0) {
           returnString = returnString +" maxlength=\""+maxLength+"\"";
       }
        if(required == true) {
            returnString = returnString + " required=\"" + required + "\"";
        }

        returnString = returnString + ">";


        return returnString;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

O problema não é a falta de instância.

Para que a linha

```
String label = annotation.label();
```

lance uma `NullPointerException`, o retorno do método chamado em

```
Campo annotation = classMethods[0].getAnnotation(Campo.class);
```

deve ser nulo.

Segundo a [documentação](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#getAnnotation-java.lang.Class-) do método, ele retorna nulo caso a anotação desejada não esteja presente no método em questão.

Dessa forma, é bem provável que o problema seja causado pelo fato de método que está na primeira posição de `classMethods[]` não estar *anotado* com a anotação `@Campo`.

---

**EDIT:**

Respondendo a pergunta (mesmo que não seja a causa do problema): para criar uma nova instância a partir de `Class<?> wantedClass` você pode fazer:

```
wantedClass.newInstance();
```

Vale lembrar que esse método lança uma `IllegalAccessException`.